# Data Flow process in ETL architecture

Tags: etl, data-warehouse

I need some clarity on how data will flow from source system to target system in a typical ETL data warehouse architecture.
For e.g. Source system, target system and ETL server are in three different networks and in ETL there are some transformations and logic applied. In this case whether data flows from source->ETL server->Target server or Source->Target with transformations applied on fly between them and data not flowing through ETL server?

Comment: source->ETL server->Target server : transformation logic get applied on ETL server

Answer (score 1):

In most situations (I can't think of an exception, but there must be some), the data moves from the source system to the ETL server and then to the target server. Transformations take place on the ETL server, which can often cause a bottleneck if that machine is under-powered or light on memory. If that turns out to be the case, an ELT approach may become necessary. Most ETL tools can easily accommodate that approach, though.

Anything more specific will depend on the specific ETL product you're using and your server architecture.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there are two different methods of ETL, Pipeline and multistage.

1- In pipeline method there is no ETL server or staging area and transformation -(including data cleansing, validation, format revision  and etc) applied At the same time with Extract step and then the transformed data load on target server. In other hand, you may run transformation program on source or target server.

2- In multistage method you have at least 3 servers (or distinct spaces): source, staging and target. for example on a database, these can be 3 separate database servers or 3 schemas on a database. Anyway, transformation program should be ran in staging area. the area is the space that you should write extracted date over it and then some transformation will be applied on extracted data. in this area you may have many stages. for example you can write extracted data on stg1 tables or files. after that, transformation_step_1 will be applied on stg1 data and the transformed data will be written on stg2 tables or files.
According to the application you may need to apply transformation_step_2 on stg2 files and write transformed data on stg3 tables or files. this process can be continued until you apply all transformations. so you may call this process Multistage ETL.

I proffer multistage method because written program in this method is easier to debug and won't use full RAM. one of the disadvantages of this method is a lot of use of storage.